# SQL downfalls of this naming convention?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

This is a two part question, so any advice on either part is welcome. I am also using PostgreSQL.

**Question 1**
So I have read through some of the threads about naming conventions for constraints for a project I am working on. Since its in the early stages, I would like to get it right.

I notice the majority here (and other sources) suggest doing something along the lines of `fk_activetable_referencedtable_fieldname`. As an example, if I had a two tables, one called `user` and the other being `posts`. A foreign key on the posts table going to user table and id field might look something along the lines of `fk_posts_user_id`.

I was thinking that a better choice would be `fk_referencedtable_fieldname_activetable`. That way, in a sense, it would follow a similar pattern as naming things sequentially, e.g., fk_user_id1, fk_user_id2, etc; where instead of at the end it would be 1,2,3,4, the end would signify the table that the foreign key is located. Therefore using the example above my foreign key would be named `fk_user_id_post`. Currently its easier to see all my foreign keys for a primary key by naming it this way, but its not the end of the world if there is better reason to do it a different way.

Are there any downsides to doing it this way?

**Question 2**
How do you handle situations where suppose you have a table where the first three columns are all foreign keys to the same primary key on a different table?

Using the same example as the above, if you had a `usertree` table where the first column (named `user_id`) identified the `id` from the `user` table, the second column (named `user_pid`), also goes to the same primary key as the `user` table, however stores the value of the parent user. The final column following the same convention as the previous (named `user_rid`), stores the value of the top level parent in the hierarchy.

At the present moment, I am not sure if its just better to make a foreign key where the name is `fk_user_id_usertree` (since they all technically reference the user table, id field) or something along the lines of `fk_user_id_user_pid_user_rid_usertree` which I feel would increase on characters and potentially hit the character limit with fields that are not so short.

Unfortunately I don't have a vast experience with SQL, so I would appreciate any insight anyone can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

**On the first question:**

I really dont generate my foreign key names anymore as my framework does it for me now. But this is the convention I used and the convention used by many generators on backend frameworks. For example, I've seen two types of conventions. Suppose you have two tables `Users` and `Cars`, then a foreign key among them will be:

Ex --> `car_id` is define on `user_id` then:

1. `fk-users-car_id`  (Users is the table where you are adding the FK and `car_id` is the field)
2. `fk-users_cars-car_id` (First the table where adding the FK and second the referenced table, then the foreign key)

On indexes:

- idx-users-car_id

**On your second question:**

I would add a foreign key for each of the fields and would follow one of the conventions above. Foreign keys added like this:

```
fk_user_id_usertree 
fk_user_pid_usertree
fk_user_rid_usertree
```

Some conventions on different dialects:

- SQL Server : `FK_ForeignKeyTable_PrimaryKeyTable`
- InnoDB (MySQL): `fk_[referencing table name]_[referenced table name]_[referencing field name]`

  For Postgres you can check --> `ADD table_constraint`
  [Postgres constraint documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

  > This form adds a new constraint to a table using the same syntax as
  >   CREATE TABLE